# binary distance k prototype

Tags: clustering, binary-data, mixed-type-data

I am using k-prototype for my mixed data set.
I've chosen Euclidean Distance for my numeric variables;
which (dis)similiraty measure can I chose for my categorical variable?
The variables ask e.g. for : for what do you use your bike?
people could chose all answers that apply, e.h.
- shopping
- seeing friends
- go to work
- having fun
...
i transformed each answer to a binary variable.
can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "objective" way to computer distances.

It is very much depending on your data and *intentions*.

So you need to experiment to find a function that quantifies similarity in a way that is appropriate for your task. You don't want too much weight on a single variable just because it has many different answers, etc.

Comment: As the binary variables are symmetric, I've chosen the Jaccard coefficient as a similarity measure because it threats positive matches and negative matches in the same way (Brian Everitt, Sabine Landau, Morven Leese, & Daniel Stahl, 2011).

Comment: It doesn't. Jaccard ignores negative matches. It only uses positive matches and differences. If you added a new option that nobody chose, the distances would not change. If you added a new option that everybody chose, it would.

Comment: ai! Thank you for letting me know, I misunderstood something! So the similarity measure of Gower and Legendre (1986) (but there exist two...I have to figure out the difference) seems to be appropriate one

Comment: As the binary variables are symmetric ,the Simple- Matching  coefficient is the appropriate  similiraty measure because it threats positive matches and negative matches in the same way (Bacher et al., 2011; Brian Everitt, Sabine Landau, Morven Leese, & Daniel Stahl, 2011).
This is how I solved it by now

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the distance-based clustering is to consider model-based clustering. Model-based clustering is usually achieved via mixture models, hence it does not require to define dissimilarity measures. However, you have to define the model at hand. Different models (e.g., number of clusters, distribution within clusters) can be considered, but information criterion (e.g., BIC, ICL...) can be used for model selection.

Because you have a mixed data set, you can use the R package VarSelLCM. It also proposes a procedure for variable selection in clustering and a shiny application to help the interpretation of the clustering results.

Here is an example of R script where x is the data.frame you want to cluster:

```
library(VarSelLCM)

# clustering without variable selection (number of components between 1 and 3)
res.noselec <- VarSelCluster(x, 1:3, vbleSelec = FALSE)

# clustering with variable selection (number of components between 1 and 3)
res.selec <- VarSelCluster(x, 1:3, vbleSelec = TRUE)

summary(res.noselec)
summary(res.selec)

VarSelShiny(res.selec)
```